# Сравнение массивов по конкретному индексу

Tags: javascript, массивы, foreach

У меня есть функция, которая проверяет имеют ли два массива одинаковые элементы. С данными массивами она проходит как `true`, из-за того что, на 5-ой итерации цикла `forEach` при сравнении (`aEl === bEl`) она сравнивает a[4] и b[3]. Подскажите пожалуйста какие условия нужно выставить что бы она проверяла `a[4]` и `b[4]` ?

Порядок элементов в массиве может быть разный.

```js
const a = [3364, 1225, 49, 900, 900],
      b = [3364, 1225, 49, 900, 901]

const compare = (a, b) => {
  if (!a || !b) return false
  let count = 0
  a.forEach(aEl => {
    if (b.some(bEl => aEl === bEl)) count++
  });
  return count === a.length
}
```

Comment: Не используйте some. Используйте, например, индексы `a[i] === b[i]`. А что делать, если длины массивов разные?

Comment: Длины массивов всегда совпадают

Comment: Длины совпадают — не в реальной жизни.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"Порядок элементов в массиве может быть разный." — Тогда хорошо бы отбрасывать совпадения после каждого сравнения... чтобы [0,0,0,0] не оказалось равным [0,1,1,1]

```js
var a = [1, 17, 256, 4, 19];
var b = [17, 1, 19, 256, 4];

function compare(a, b){
  var bb = b.slice(0); //Клонируем массив, чтобы функция не трогала его.
  for( var i = 0; i < a.length; i++ ){
    var index = bb.indexOf( a[i] );
    if( !~index ){ // Как только очередного элемента из a на будет в b - false.
      return false
    } else {
      bb.splice( index, 1 );// Иначе, после каждого совпадения удаляем совпадение
      console.log( bb.join() );
    }
  }
  return true; // Если дошло сюда, значит до этого всё совпало.
}

console.log( compare(a,b) );
```

P.s.

```js
let arr = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];

arr.forEach(function( элемент, индекс, массив ){
  массив[индекс] = элемент * 2;
});

console.log( arr.join() );

// Не создавайте переменные на русском ))
```

Comment: а почему проста не клонировать массив нормально ? к примеру `const bb = b;` как разница между вашим вариантом `var bb = b.slice(0);`?

Comment: @Demon __ ANT Массивы - частный случай объектов (с числовыми ключами). А в случае объектов если написать `var a = {hello: true;}` то `a` будет являться ссылкой на объект а не самим объектом. Т.е. потом можно сделать `var b = a;` (скопировали ссылку на объект), а в этом объекте что-то можно менять и через новую ссылку: `b.hello = 'bubu';` и тогда при `console.log(a)` выведется `{hello: bubu;}`. Так и тут, если написать `bb = b`, тогда все изменения с bb будут касаться и b ( а на самом деле они оба будут ссылаться на один массив ) → https://jsfiddle.net/OPTlMUS/q0oh17t2/1/

Comment: O_o спасибо огромное да про ссылочные типы  я не подумал.И последний вопрос.В гугле ничего не нашел про этот побитовый оператор который вы используете `!~`.Что  он делает?

Comment: `!` в условиях означает отрицание... `!false` будет `true`. А `~` сам не понимаю, как работает, но берет любое число, меняет его знак и отнимает единицу. `~10 == -11` // `~(-5) == 4` // Но в логическом контексте любое число кроме ноля = true. А `indexOf` как раз выводит -1 только если совпадений не найдено. Вот и выходит ~(-1) == 0... т.е. false, если совпадения нет. Ну и `!~(-1)` будет true.

Comment: спасибо за объяснение 1+ с меня :)

Comment: в первом примере, функция `compare` всегда возвращает `true`. В цикле, `return false` не работает. Там нужна использовать continue/break и внешнюю переменную (flag);

Comment: @Дмытрык  https://jsfiddle.net/OPTlMUS/98jctfeL/ - ну на этом примере возвращает false...

Answer (score 3):

Предлагаю вот такой фокус, основанный на побитовом исключающем или `^`, оно вернет 0 для идентичных значений...

```js
const a = [3364, 49, 900, 900, 1225],
      b = [3364, 1225, 49, 900, 900],
      c = [3364, 1225, 49, 900, 901];

let sort = a => a.sort((a, b) => a - b);

let check = (a, b) => {
  a = sort(a), b = sort(b);
  return !a.reduce((a, e, i) => a || b[i]^e, 0);
}


console.log("ab =", check(a, b))
console.log("ac =", check(a, c))
```

---

Похожий вариант:

```js
const a = [3364, 49, 900, 900, 1225],
      b = [3364, 1225, 49, 900, 900],
      c = [3364, 1225, 49, 900, 901];

let diff = (a, b) => a - b;
let check = (a, b) => !a.sort(diff)
                       .reduce((a, e, i) => (a[i]^=e, a), b.sort(diff))
                       .reduce(diff);

console.log("ab =", check(a, b))
console.log("ac =", check(a, c))
```

Answer (score 0):

Заглянуть в документацию, в ваш учебник, увидеть подсказку в ide и чудесным образом обнаружить, что forEach в callBack 3 параметра передает

Comment: "ваш учебник"? А можно подробнее?